# Overlapping two divs and 'clearing' their parent div

Tags: css, css-position, overlap

My CSS-fu is letting me down here:
What I'd like to do is position two child divs (with **variable** heights) to be overlapping.

Using: `position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;` is the only way I know how, with the parent set to `position: relative`.

The problem with this is that the child divs are taken out of the layout as per the CSS spec, shrinking the parent div to height: 0px, so that I can't clear that div and put any content below.

My amazing ASCII art below details what I'm going for... any ideas?

As an aside, I need these divs to be overlapping exactly for smooth jQuery fades, and maybe trying out some of the new Webkit transforms, a la Apple's cardflip demo:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CardFlip/Introduction/Intro.html

If there's another way to get them overlapped exactly in CSS, and/or if there's another way to get cardflip-like action (using jQuery or Webkit/CSS) with two child divs of variable heights, I'm all ears!

```
|-------------------------------------------------|
|  Parent div                                     |
|  |-------------------------------------------|  |
|  |                                           |  |
|  |          DIVS 1 & 2 (overlapped)          |  |
|  |                                           |  |
|  |-------------------------------------------|  |
|-------------------------------------------------|

...more content below, after clearing the parent...
```

Comment: how can they be overlapping _exactly_ with variable heights..?

Comment: Pardon me, I can see how that would be confusing. What I meant by exactly was that they were both positioned exactly at top: 0px, left: 0px.
The bottom margins (obviously) won't necessarily match up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just setting one of them to `postition:absolute`? That way one child div will still give height to the parent div, but the other will be taken out of the flow.

```
.parent { position: relative; }
.child1 { position: absolute; top:0; left:0; }
.child2 { position: relative; }
```

Just a jQuery suggestion:

```
var height1 = $(".child1").height();
var height2 = $(".child2").height();
if(height1 > height2)
    $(".child2").height(height1);
else
    $(".child1").height(height2);
```

And now you'll have seamless fades between the two `<div>`'s

Comment: One problem I could see with this solution is that you would have to know in advance which child will be taller. Using your sample code, if child 1 is significantly taller than child 2, it will overlap outside of its parent div.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I made the comment above about how they can be overlapping when they vary in height... I'm confused.

Comment: I love this idea! Getting so close to working... any ideas for figuring out which div is higher? I could do this in javascript easily enough, but if we could pull it off in CSS, even better.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that with CSS alone. CSS isn't really good for doing checks (unless you're targeting IE alone (`CSS expressions`))...

Answer (score 0):

What about `position: relative` and negative margins?

Off the top of my head:

```
.parent {}

.child1 {
    height: 200px;
}

.child2 {
    margin-top: -200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: That would work great, and I had thought of that, except both children have variable heights (varying amounts of text in each). Thanks, I've updated the question above to reflect that.