# How can I get text to appear on top of text inside a <div>

Tags: html, css

I have:

```
<div>
   <div>xxx</div>
   <div>yyy</div>
<div>
```

How can I make it so the "yyy" appears on top (as in overwrites) the "xxx" and both are visible?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/GuRMP/ - @Samanthaj

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overlapping two divs and 'clearing' their parent div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986587/overlapping-two-divs-and-clearing-their-parent-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the outer div `position: relative;` and the two inner divs `position: absolute`.

By default, the location of a `position: absolute` div is top left, so both will be at the top left of the parent div, one on top of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy way

```
<div style="position:relative">
   <div>xxx</div>
   <div style="position:absolute;top:9px">yyy</div>
<div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/naAj9/

Comment: Only works if there is no other content above it, and the text is 9px high, and many other conditions.

Comment: Remember, that you have to make `position:relative` to the container `div`, otherwise, the absolute position of the nested `div` will be calculated according to the main container.

Comment: @sevenseacat :) you are right. its just a POC. as i said, quick and easy. in reallife, they will adjust to the needs. afterall, stackover is not copy paste. its trail and learn.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div>
   <div >xxx</div>
   <div class="z-in">yyy</div>
<div>
```

css:

```
.z-in
{
   position: relative;
   bottom: 20px;
}
```